# How do I align a smaller model's y-position to the y-position of a point on a larger model (like a heightmap)?

Tags: 3d, libgdx

I'm currently trying place small models on a large terrain, I place the small models randomly along the x and z axis but I want them to use the y-position of the point in the terrain that's under them. Here's a picture of what I am currently doing:

[image: Terrain]

As you can see, the small models are clipping through the terrain because they are all set at a predetermined y-position.

The terrain is a single model generated from a mesh. like so:

```
modelBuilder.begin();
int c = 0;              
for (int z = 0; z < chunksHeight; z++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < chunksWidth; x++) {

        chunks[c] = new TerrainChunk(octaves, octaveCount, scale,
                strength, x, z, chunkBorderWidth,isIsland);

        Mesh mesh = new Mesh(false, chunks[c].vertices.length / 3,
                chunks[c].indices.length, 
                new VertexAttribute(Usage.Position, 3, ShaderProgram.POSITION_ATTRIBUTE),
                new VertexAttribute(Usage.Normal, 3,ShaderProgram.NORMAL_ATTRIBUTE),
                new VertexAttribute(Usage.ColorPacked, 4,ShaderProgram.COLOR_ATTRIBUTE),
                new VertexAttribute(Usage.TextureCoordinates, 2,ShaderProgram.TEXCOORD_ATTRIBUTE));

        mesh.setVertices(chunks[c].vertices);
        mesh.setIndices(chunks[c].indices);
        modelBuilder.node();
        modelBuilder.part("chunk" + Integer.toString(x) + "-" + Integer.toString(z),
                mesh,
                GL20.GL_TRIANGLES,
                new Material());
        c++;
    }
}
terrainModel = modelBuilder.end();
```

So my question is how do I tell my small models where their y-position is?

Edit: I guess what I'm really asking is how do I get the y coordinate of a mesh if I already have the x and z coordinates.

Comment: maybe this helps you out http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/24572/how-does-terrain-following-work-on-height-map